# Активация виртуального окружения python3, которое было создано на windows, в ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, ubuntu, venv

Подскажите, пожалуйста, создал вирт окружение на windows 10, перенес копию на вирт машину ubuntu с помощью яндекс диска. При активации этого окружения появляются левые библиотеки.
Для сравнения привожу скрины созданного venv на линуксе и скопированного и их библиотеки.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И показываю, как на винде это выглядит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это так не работает. Созданный virtualenv очень привязан к системе, нет гарантии, что даже перенос с линукса на линукс той же версии будет работать. Нужно создать virtualenv заново и туда установить все пакеты.

Answer (score 0):

То как вы это делаете, весьма странно.
Обычный флоу работы на разных машинах выглядит следующим образом:

1. Создаем окружение
2. Устанавливаем необходимые пакеты
3. Сохраняем зависимости в `requirements.txt`

```bsh
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

4. Переносим файл requirements.txt на другой компьютер и выполняем установку из файла зависимостей в необходимом окружении.

```bsh
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Таким образом можно легко воспрозизводить окружение сколько угодно раз. На разных ОС.

P.S.
Для версионирования и перемещения кода и файла зависимостей лучше использовать Git. Даже самое базовое использование решает большенство(я бы даже сказал все) проблем с переносом кода между машинами.